# After changing PHP version, Joomla cannot connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, joomla

I have Joomla 3.3.3 in a server where PHP 5.3.29 is installed.

I requested the hosting team (Hostgator) to install PHP 5.5.28 side by side.

When they told me the task was finished, I added these lines to the top of .htaccess file:

```
# PHP 5.5
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php55/lib
</IfModule>
```

After that, I tried to load the page and this error was shown, in both front end an in administration pages:

```
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL.
```

If I remove the added lines in .htaccess, site works again.

What may be hapenning here?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that they haven't installed the mysql extension, you can compare the versions of php using a simple [phpinfo script](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php):

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Run this in your browser using both PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.5 and scroll down the the 'mysql/mysqli/mysqlnd' section which will tell you whether it's been installed with the mysql extension or not, if it hasn't been contact your host and ask them to add it.

If you're running on a vps or similar you can also check `apt`/`dnf`/`yum` to check for package differences:

- `apt list --installed | grep php`
- `dnf list --installed | grep php`
- `yum list installed | grep php`

If you see you have a lot of packages prefixed with `php53-` and only a few with `php55-` you could ask them to install the missing packages, for example (using brew on OSX), if I list with brew there is a clear difference between packages I have installed for `php56` and `php71`:

```
user@comp ~ $ brew list | grep php
php56
php56-mcrypt
php56-memcache
php56-mongo
php56-xdebug
php71
php71-xdebug
```

In this situation I would ask the host to install `php71-mcrypt`, `php71-memcache` and `php71-mongo` or equivalents.

Comment: It is strange. The only accepted command was "yum list installed | grep php". When I ran that, only a lot of packages that start with "cpanel-php54" were listed and no more else. For example, "cpanel-php54.i386                                5.4.31-4.cp1156       installed"

Comment: By the way... phpinfo only works with PHP 5.3. when changed to PHP 5.5, Joomla intercepts phpinfo execution showing the error. I have found that something was wrong with MySQL in this server, because I changed driver to mysqli and now, no connection error occurs but only a blank page is shown :-(..... the strange thing is that this same application works well in my development server, where I have mysql driver configured and PHP 5.5.28

Comment: For the white screen check your error_log, it's likely that the server is throwing a 500 error when you change to mysqli.

Comment: no error is logged, neither error_log of Apache nor logs folder in Joomla

Comment: Can you run anything on php 5.5? Even a simple php file that just echos a single word?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the most common reason for this problem (in your scenario) is when the mysql[i] package is not compatible with the version of PHP installed. Usually, the host takes care of the problem (I would bug them about it).

You can check the installation of mysqli on a Centos environment here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php